# Узнать через WMI(Или другим программным способом) наличие в IIS URL-Rewrite

Tags: iis, wmi

Подскажите, можно ли через WMI узнать есть ли на сайте URL-Rewrite?

Интересует вот эта инфа:

[image]

Рылся в классах WMI, но пока ничего подходящего не нашел...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нашел решение в виде проверки виртуальных директорий и сайтов на предмет наличия web.config и если он имеется, то проверяю наличие там узла rewrite.